# Extracting file with folders then using bash completion

Tags: bash, tar

I don't work much with bash scripting and was trying to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-i686-static.tar.xz
tar xvf ffmpeg-git-i686-static.tar.xz
cd ./ffmpeg-git-20210501-i686-static/
cp ./ffmpeg-git-20210501-i686-static/ffmpeg /etc/bin
```

Is there a variable or a way I can determine what that extracted folder is called during script execution. For example with bash completion at the command line I would use cd ./ffmpeg (since I know it starts with ffmpeg)

Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know beforehand the directory structure, but you can use a wildcard in the copy command:

```sh
cp ./*/ffmpeg /etc/bin
```

Although, I do not recommend installing tarball extracted executable within `/etc/bin`.

I'd put a symbolic link inside `/usr/local/bin/` instead:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

__opwd="$PWD"
trap 'cd "$__opwd"' EXIT ABRT INT

wget https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-i686-static.tar.xz || exit 1

# Create place where to install the unpacked archive
mkdir -p '/opt/ffmpeg-git-i686-static' || exit 1

# Unpack the archive
cd '/opt/ffmpeg-git-i686-static' || exit 1
tar xf "$__opwd/ffmpeg-git-i686-static.tar.xz" || exit 1

# Create a symbolic link from the ffmpeg command into `/usr/local/bin/`
ln -sf /opt/ffmpeg-git-i686-static/*/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it also better to use /usr/bin/env sh instead of /bin/bash?

Comment: @MickeyD `#!/usr/bin/env sh` will run POSIX shell from whatever environment `$PATH` it is installed in.  `#!/bin/bash` will run bash from this exact location or will fail if not available in `/bin`. So the former is the most portable shebang. Similarly: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` would run bash, regardless of its installed location.